ReactJS function takes a double of click to be triggered
I have 2 functions, function uploadFile uploads the file image to firebase and then store the returned url through setState, and function saveTeam which send a request to /new-team-member with payload including the returned url
const uploadFile = async () => {
  const imageRef = storageRef(storage, `images/${UniqueComponentId()}`);
  uploadBytes(imageRef, team.image)
    .then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
        .then((url) => {
          setTeam({ ...team, url: url || team.image });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
};

const saveTeam = async () => {
  setSubmitted(true);
  let _teams = [...teams];
  let _team = { ...team };
  if (team.id) {
    await fetch('https://bunaq-api.vercel.app/api/edit-team-member', {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(team),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
    const index = findIndexById(team.id);
    _teams[index] = _team;
    toast.current.show({
      severity: 'success',
      summary: 'Successful',
      detail: t('adminTeamPage.new.toastUpdated'),
      life: 5000,
    });
  } else {
    fetch('https://bunaq-api.vercel.app/api/new-team-member', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(team),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
    _teams.unshift(_team);
    // location.reload();
    toast.current.show({
      severity: 'success',
      summary: 'Successful',
      detail: t('adminTeamPage.new.toastCreated'),
      life: 5000,
    });
  }
  setTeams(_teams);
  setTeamDialog(false);
  setTeam(emptyTeam);
};

const saveTeamMain = async () => {
  await uploadFile();
  saveTeam();
};

<button onClick={saveTeamMain}>Save</button>;

But when i click Save it doesn't do anything for the first time, and then triggers the function on the second click, why is that happening ?

From your description it seems like you should be waiting for the (presumably) asynchronous uploadFile() function to complete. If that saves the URL into state, you'd also need to properly wait for that state to change using an effect hook before calling saveTeam(). This question really needs a [mre] to completely understand it though

Are there errors in the Javascript console? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them like you are now!

Does this answer your question? The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately

Also Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference

my problem is that the function takes 2 clicks to work, when i click save the first time, nothing happens and no errors, when i click it after that (second time), everything works fine

please read my question title, if it was "why setState doesn't reflect change" then your answers would be relatable

It seems you haven't read the linked post. Calling setTeam() won't apply changes to team until the next render cycle. You need to use an effect hook to watch for team changes. You're also not waiting for the uploadBytes() promise to resolve

The reason you have to click twice is because even though you await uploadFile, since upload file uses .then & .catch it returns immediately and runs saveTeam immediately before uploadFile completes.  So all the state setting happening in uploadFile is happening after saveTeam runs.
You should convert uploadFile to await syntax.
const uploadFile = async () => {
  const imageRef = storageRef(storage, `images/${UniqueComponentId()}`);
try{
  const snapshot = await uploadBytes(imageRef, team.image)
  const url = await getDownloadUrl(snapshot.ref)
  setTeam({...team, url:url || team.image})
  return

  }catch(err){
    console.log(err.message)
  }
};

Even when properly awaiting uploadFile, if you are expecting to set state in uploadFile then read that state in the syncronously invoked function of saveTeam I believe you're still going to have stale state.

yeah its still going to have stale state, the solution to that as @Phill mentioned, function saveTeam should be put in useEffect

Could also just return the necessary values from uploadFile and pass them to saveTeam as arguments.  It's also unclear from the code he's provided if these values need to be stateful at all.

The reason I suspect some of these values don't need to be stateful is that he sets team in uploadFile then immediately sets team to emptyTeam in saveTeam.  If these values are not intended to cause a change in the DOM then there is no reason to use state. Better to use a ref or simply return the values from uploadFile and consume them with saveTeam
